# Dialog showing only 1 button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I made an app and inserted a dialog in it using DialogFragment, by reading the instructions on the officila android developers site. I made a dialog with 3 buttons, each having a different function. However, when I run it, only 1 button is displayed (mxed fraction). Why is that so?
Here's the code:

```
package com.example.fractionscalculator;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialogFragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

public class specifyInput extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Please specify the type of number you entered.");
        builder.setTitle("Set format");
        builder.setNeutralButton("Regular Fraction", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getandsetText1("frac");

            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("Whole Number", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getandsetText1("whole");
            }
        });
        builder.setNeutralButton("Mixed Fraction", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getandsetText1("mixed");
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

I am a beginner in java and android, so if it is a stupid mistake, please go easy on me.

Comment: because you're setting neutral button twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use 3 kind of predefined action button like : so you have used `setNeutralButton` 3 time its override that button and only show 1 time.

```
dialog.setPositiveButton(..);
dialog.setNegativeButton(..);
dialog.setNeutralButton(..);
```

as per documentation :

There are three different action buttons you can add:

- **Positive** : You should use this to accept and continue with the action (the "OK" action).
- **Negative** : You should use this to cancel the action.
- **Neutral** : You should use this when the user may not want to proceed with the action, but doesn't necessarily want to cancel. It appears between the positive and negative buttons. For example, the action might be "Remind me later."